nginx not showing index.php as default
I created a docker image to server PHP code based on nginx. Everything seems to work quite well except that my request URL always needs to contain index.php (like: http://myserver.com/inde.php). If I skip "index.php" nginx will deliver just the welcome page and not automatically use index.php.
My Dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.16.2
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    bash \
    php8 \ 
    php8-fpm \ 
    php8-json \
    php8-mbstring \
    php8-mysqlnd \
    php8-pdo \
    php8-pdo_mysql \
    php8-pdo_pgsql \
    php8-pdo_sqlite \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libltdl 

RUN apk add openssl curl ca-certificates

RUN printf "%s%s%s\n" \
"http://nginx.org/packages/alpine/v" \
`egrep -o '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' /etc/alpine-release` \
"/main" \
| tee -a /etc/apk/repositories

RUN curl -o /tmp/nginx_signing.rsa.pub https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.rsa.pub
RUN openssl rsa -pubin -in /tmp/nginx_signing.rsa.pub -text -noout
RUN mv /tmp/nginx_signing.rsa.pub /etc/apk/keys/
RUN apk add nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./index.php /usr/share/nginx/html/
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "php-fpm8 && chmod 755 /usr/share/nginx/html/* && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]

My default.conf:
server {

    listen *:80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name myserver;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        # gzip_static on;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

}

Any idea what I need to fix in my setup to directly get the index.php delivered when requesting http://myserver.com?

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [sf] would be better places for questions like this.

Docker is a bit of an edge case and if you read the tag description, it says "As a rule of thumb, if your question is about something happening inside the container, it's probably on-topic here.". I would say this question is on-topic for SO.

"will deliver just the welcome page" What welcome page? Do you also have an index.html in the doc root?

@AlexHowansky The default welcome page from nginx that says "Welcome to nginx!
If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.
For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.
Thank you for using nginx."

How about the docker-compose.yml file? Under the nginx container, you should also have volume mounting your project to /usr/share/nginx/html

@Mr.Kenneth I load the php files from my Dockerfile directly into the image (deleted it from the code above, but it is there in production). And they do really arrie in the container - checked it with docker exec and also when adding /index.php to the URL.

I found the answer in Nginx together with haproxy does not point the root index.php file
Since my environment is running behind a proxy (traefik) obviously nginx gets messed a little with the filesystem.
Copying the content from the default.conf into the file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf into the http {...} section.
